# udevlib Does udevlib work with mdev

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, udev

We have to enumerate usb devices on board. Can we build busybox with mdev instead of udev?
Can we also use udevlib functions in case we have mdev on board.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Nice explanation in [Hallinan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137017839), if you google "19.8.1 busybox mdev" you may get everything you need for this topic (but, also buy the book, it's really great). Yes, remove udev but keep hotplug and sysfs, refer also maybe to [gentoo/mdev](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Mdev).